# Object yet to be deleted by GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

So the garbage collector does not deletes object immediately, is there any way to set the reference to the object which is already eligible for GC?

`Object o = new Object();
o = null; // above object is eligible for GC
// now can we retrieve the above object? as it is not destroyed by GC`

Comment: GC can only free memory of objects that are **unreachable**. If the object is unreachable, how would you reach it to retrieve it again? You cannot. That's what "unreachable" means. Why would you even want to?

Comment: Why would you want to do it ?

Comment: out of curiosity that, JVM doesn't run GC immediately, so there must be some way to that, I thought!

Comment: @AkshayGautam: no, there's no way. Some possible optimizations *depend* on that not being possible. For example if the JVM sees that the object can never "escape" the bounds of the method, then it might not actually allocate the object on the stack, but just represent its values in registers. That is a very useful optimization, but it would break if there were a way to get "unreachable objects".

Comment: Without additional bookkeeping (like the `WeakReference` used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53977135/2711488)), the runtime does not even know that the unreachable object ever existed. So it’s impossible to resurrect an unreachable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object o = new Object();
WeakReference<Object> weakReference = new WeakReference<>(o);
o = null;

o = weakReference.get();
```

You can *weakly* refer to the object the references of which you want to nullify. It will be available (more precisely, [weakly reachable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html)) via `weakReference.get()` unless it's been cleared by the GC.

Of course, it becomes fully unreachable if no references of any kind (strong/soft/weak/phantom) relate to it.